# Isolate code dependencies in dag by using container - airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to use `apache-airflow` and i'd like to explore `Docker` to run task in container.

My current airflow installation is in a dedicated virtualenv and airflow is restarted automatically with systemd.

I have already multiple projects I want to take on Airflow. 
Each project should have its own dag.
I'd like to have the project dag written with `PythonOperator` and run inside a docker container with  an image that I've previously built with all the correct dependencies.

This could guarantee code dependencies to be isolated between each project.

Is it achieavable somehow?

Answer (score 1):

There is a DockerOperator:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html

As well as a PythonVirtualEnvironmentOperator:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.PythonVirtualenvOperator

Anyway, within a PythonOperator you can code whatever you want, so you can create there a new virtual environment, install the dependencies and build a docker image

Comment: PythonVirtualEnvOperator is not a viable solution. It creates and destroy virtualenv on the fly.